# Where do I prove that a return type is valid?

Tags: lean4

I am learning Lean 4 by implementing a fixed-length vector type.

Type definition:

```
    inductive Vec (α : Type u) : Nat → Type u
  | nil  : Vec α 0
  | cons : α → Vec α n → Vec α (n+1)
```

I have attempted to write a recursive function to concatenate two of these vectors

```
def concat {n m : Nat} (xs : Vec α n) (ys : Vec α m) : Vec α (n + m) :=
  match n, m, xs, ys with
  | 0, m, nil, ys => ys
  | (Nat.succ n), m, cons x xs, ys => cons x (concat xs ys)
```

However, this fails to typecheck with the following error:

```
error: type mismatch
  nil
has type
  Vec α 0 : Type ?u.5777
but is expected to have type
  Vec α (0 + m) : Type ?u.5777
```

If i replace the right-hand side in the `xs = nil` with `sorry` i get a similar error for the other case (`Vec α (n + m + 1)` and `Vec α (Nat.succ n + m)`).

How/where do i provide a proof that my return type is valid?

Comment: IIRC matching on `ys` instead is much easier (this is called "defeq abuse"), but you can also make it work with `xs` too.

Comment: @Trebor Can you define concatenation of cons-vectors by matching on `ys`?  I know how to do it with snoc-vectors, but cons-vectors seem (curiously!) to be a poor match for the "usual" definition of nat-addition by matching on the right-hand argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions:

```
inductive Vec (α : Type u) : Nat → Type u
  | nil  : Vec α 0
  | cons : α → Vec α n → Vec α (n+1)

def Vec.concat : {n m : Nat} -> (xs : Vec α n) -> (ys : Vec α m) -> Vec α (m + n)
  | 0, _, nil,       ys => ys
  | _, _, cons x xs, ys => cons x (concat xs ys)

theorem Vec.vec_n_plus_m_equals_m_plus_n : Vec α (n + m) = Vec α (m + n) := by
  rw [Nat.add_comm]

def Vec.concat' : {n m : Nat} -> (xs : Vec α n) -> (ys : Vec α m) -> Vec α (n + m)
  | 0, _, nil,       ys => vec_n_plus_m_equals_m_plus_n ▸ ys
  | _, _, cons x xs, ys => vec_n_plus_m_equals_m_plus_n ▸ cons x (concat xs ys)

-- pretty print Vec as a list
def Vec.toList : Vec α n -> List α
  | nil       => []
  | cons x xs => x :: toList xs 

instance [Repr α] : Repr (Vec α n)  where
  reprPrec v := v.toList.repr

-- test that the code works
def vec0 := Vec.cons 0 Vec.nil
def vec1 := Vec.cons 1 Vec.nil
#eval vec0               -- [0]
#eval vec1               -- [1]
#eval vec0.concat vec1   -- [0, 1]
#eval vec0.concat' vec1  -- [0, 1]
```

The first just swaps the order of addition to `Vec α (m + n)`.  The reason this works is that Lean defines addition with recursion on the right argument.  (At least one reason for this is that `n + 1` reduces to `Nat.succ n` [making match statements look more readable](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/2439/122).)

If that is untenable, you can alternately use `▸` to cast your output type to the desired type.  You just need to prove the two output types are equal.

---

Also, I took the liberty to rewrite your code in more of a Lean 4 style.  In particular, if you name your function `Vec.concat` (or open the `Vec` namespace), then you can get some nice advantages:

- It organizes your code by putting everything related to vectors under the `Vec` namespace.
- You don't have to add `Vec.` inside the body of your function.
- You can use your function as either `Vec.concat v1 v2` or `v1.concat v2`.